# Using pattern to select files that has XX at any part the name in R

Tags: r, list, file, pattern-matching

I have a folder full of files which names are like these, for example:

```
[1] "./final_model_pre/pre_pe_ja_bc_wm.tif"          "./final_model_pre/pre_pe_ja_bc_wm.tif.aux.xml" 
 [3] "./final_model_pre/pre_pe_ja_bc_wm.tif.ovr"      "./final_model_pre/pre_an_le_glm_wm.tif"        
 [5] "./final_model_pre/pre_an_le_glm_wm.tif.aux.xml" "./final_model_pre/pre_an_le_glm_wm.tif.ovr"    
 [7] "./final_model_pre/pre_an_bo_ma_wm.tif"          "./final_model_pre/pre_an_bo_ma_wm.tif.aux.xml" 
 [9] "./final_model_pre/pre_an_bo_ma_wm.tif.ovr"      "./final_model_pre/pre_pe_ja_mx_wm.tif"         
[11] "./final_model_pre/pre_pe_ja_mx_wm.tif.aux.xml"  "./final_model_pre/pre_pe_ja_mx_wm.tif.ovr"     
[13] "./final_model_pre/pre_pe_ja_rf1_wm.tif"         "./final_model_pre/pre_pe_ja_rf1_wm.tif.aux.xml"
[15] "./final_model_pre/pre_pe_ja_rf1_wm.tif.ovr"     "./final_model_pre/pre_pe_ja_svm_wm.tif"        
[17] "./final_model_pre/pre_pe_ja_svm_wm.tif.aux.xml" "./final_model_pre/pre_pe_ja_svm_wm.tif.ovr"
```

I want to list every files that have `"pe_ja"` in the name and only with `".tif"` extension, not `".tif.ovr"` or `".tif.aux.xml"` or any other extension. I'm trying to use `list.files` function, but I couldn't manage to use the `pattern` agrument properly. Could you help me doing that? 
Thank you!
P.S.: I'm using R.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a regular expression for that.

```
files = list.files(pattern = '.*pe_ja.*\\.tif$')
```

The `$` at the end of the regular expression indicates that that is the end of the string.  The `\\.` is an escaped period, indicating that you want to match a period (not any character, which is what `.` normally matches).

The `.*` selects any character any number of times (including 0).

Answer (score 1):

try this one `files = list.files(pattern = '.*pe_ja.*\.tif$')` note that in order to escape the `.` you need this expression `\.` not `\\.` , this expression `\\.`
means escape `\` character and match any character after `.` except new line 
try this one out [Regex101 test file names](https://regex101.com/r/nE3jL8/1)

Comment: You have to use `\\.` because R first interprets the "\\" as the "\" character,  since "\" is R's escape character as well, and then the "\" character gets passed to the regex engine.